# How can PiPL.com Perform a Public search on Linkedin.com

Tags: facebook, linkedin-api

I am developing a online reputation website and i am interested in knowing how pipl searches on linkedin.com without Oauth. Can anybody tell me a way to search for people on Linkedin.com and Facebook.com without oAuth(if not API , any other way?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way Facebook allows you to do it is if you get their permission. You have to fill out this form: http://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos.php

From what I understand they don't really give that permission out unless you are already a reputable company and will block you pretty quickly if you are crawling their site without the permission.

I assume that for linkedin you only have to follow their robots.txt file which can be found here: http://www.linkedin.com/robots.txt

Comment: thanks for the reply, that information is v useful. can you let me know how can i use robots.txt to search for people on linkedin